# PostgreSQL server query execution

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL server and there's the thing I need to know about query execution on it. I have two different clients connected to the server simultaneously. Now, the clients are executing some queries at the same time. Is it true that any clien't query will be exectueted in a separated thread?

Or the server can split the query excution into multiple threads for optimization's sakes.

Comment: Each connection uses [a separate process](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/connect-estab.html) on the server. But a single query can not use more than one thread (currently)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So, if I split the query in a few parts and them in any thread(the number of threads = the number of cores) can I counting on improving performance?

Comment: @user3663882 You can only be sure performance will improve if you know the query is cpu-bound. If it's I/O bound it could improve, or it could get worse, depending on a lot of factors including PostgreSQL and kernel version, storage subsystem, etc. Before you try to optimise you should first identify the bottleneck that's limiting current performance.

Comment: @CraigRinger There're a lot of "depending on". So there's no simple answer for hte question about splitting query execution in a few parts and exectue them in a separated thread, using sperated db connections (I'm working in Java), right?

Comment: @user3663882 Correct. That's why your optimisation should be driven be testing and profiling of actual performance to find actual bottlenecks, so you're not fixing the wrong thing or making it worse.

Comment: @CraigRinger Got it, thank you.

Comment: You should also not forget that parsing a SQL query might also take some time. Sending a single statement processing a lot of rows is usually(!) faster than sending many statements processing a few rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name BTW, while I was running some experiments with a table containing 10M rows I found that processing the whole table took 20 secs on my machine, but processing a half of the table took only 7 secs (2*7 = 14 < 20). The table had two columns id (int), name(text). Did that result really make any sense? The experiments I was ran through PGAdmin, and the part was exectued simultaneously. The query was simple select retrieving all data.